# Display legend items in customized order visualizing with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit, plotly-express

Hi I am using the following code:

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


def piechart(home_win_probability, draw_game, away_win_probability, title):

    home_win_probability = round(home_win_probability, 2)
    draw_game = round(draw_game, 2)
    away_win_probability = round(away_win_probability, 2)

    labels = ['Home Win', 'Draw Game', 'Away Win']
    values = [home_win_probability, draw_game, away_win_probability]

    data = pd.DataFrame({'Category': labels, 'Value': values})

    fig = px.pie(data, names='Category', values='Value', title=title)

    # Set hover template to display the rounded value
    fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=labels)

    # Display the pie chart in Streamlit using st.plotly_chart
    st.plotly_chart(fig)

    return()
```

When I type `piechart(31.2,48.7,20.1,'Probabilities')`:

What I see:

[image]

What I would like to see:

[image]

What I tried (unsucessfully): I tried to add the following line before st.plotly_chart(fig):

```
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder=['Home Win', 'Draw Game', 'Away Win'])
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you have gone from a home win, clockwise to a draw, and then to an away win, switch to the pie chart in the graph object. `fig = go.Figure(data=go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, sort=False))`